# How to use SnakeYaml setProcessComments() on LoaderOptions and DumperOptions

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

SnakeYaml API appears to have a very interesting feature for preserving comments during both loading and dumping (`setProcessComments(true)`).  I have confirmed in the debugger that it does ingest and track the comments, as I can find them on the `Node` representation tree after using `compose(fileStream)`.  However, I have yet to find any kind of documentation of this feature or how it would be useful, especially on the output side of things.  But this certainly seems possible since `DumperOptions.setProcessComments(true)` is available.

All the documentation I've found focuses on `Map` and/or JavaBean loading and dumping, neither of which seems to be able to benefit from the comments stored on the `Node` tree.  Or, if it does, I'm not clear how.

Can anyone provide a relatively simple "round trip" example where a YAML file is loaded with comments and then dumped with comments?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Very simply, this pattern seems to work for me:

```java
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Node;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer;

// ...

LoaderOptions loadOptions = new LoaderOptions();
loadOptions.setProcessComments(true);
DumperOptions dumpOptions = new DumperOptions();
dumpOptions.setProcessComments(true);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new SafeConstructor(loadOptions), new Representer(dumpOptions), dumpOptions, loadOptions);
Node rootNode = yaml.compose(myInputStream);

// ...

yaml.serialize(rootNode, outputWriter);
```